# Google Sheets API PHP Curl Script

Tags: php, curl, post, google-sheets-api, php-curl

I am trying to access a google sheet by means of the API provided by Google. 
The following code works by inserting the data. 
My only problem is that I can not find any appropriate code to get an updated access token with a curl request and It's driving me crazy!

Does anybody have a solution so that the user does not have to enter his login data again and again? 
Maybe I can store my account data in the code?

```
$nummer = $_POST['param1'];
$komm = $_POST['param2'];
$entnommen = $_POST['param3'];
$url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1TDkPMU9EzLwV45V1CrmNU4Xscc3GH9dKc1HDTIzc16k/values/Test!A1:append?includeValuesInResponse=true&insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&valueInputOption=RAW';
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("range" => "Test!A1",
"majorDimension" => "ROWS",
"values" => array(array($nummer,$komm,$entnommen)));
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token;
$headr[] = 'Accept: application/json';
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headr,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string
));
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$statusCode = curl_getInfo($ch, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
var_dump($result);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
$character = json_decode($result);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you need to do is make a request to obtain a "refresh" token

Comment: BTW Google provides a PHP client library for their APIs which is probably going to be easier than using raw cURL requests. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php should point you in the right direction

Comment: But when I try to get the refreshToken with oauth2 playground get the following:

`"error_description": "Unauthorized", 
  "error": "unauthorized_client"`

Comment: Well I don't know the context for that, perhaps you didn't allow the playground to be an authorised app on your Google account, I have no idea. And that's not really very relevant to whether you can get the PHP code to work, either

Comment: If I would get the refresh token I can add it to my code.
Do you have an idea how I can get the refresh token with a curl? The PHP client library did not work on the server at all.

Comment: "The PHP client library did not work"...did not work how? What error did you get? Did you load the PHP client library files onto the server? If you want to make a cURL request directly to get the token, consult the API docs for what HTTP request to make. Or see what the client library does. However Google strongly recommend that you don't do this, due to the security implications of getting it wrong.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline